# Get private value from jQuery function

Tags: jquery

Here is my code

```
(function ($) {
    var Test = (function () {
        function Test(element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.getValue = "";
            this.init();
        }

        return Test;
    })();
    Test.prototype.init = function () {
        this.getValue = $(this.element).val();
    };

    $.fn.Test = function () {
        // iterate and reformat each matched element
        return this.each(function () {
            return new Test(this);
        })
    };
})(jQuery);
```

`return this.each` is designed to protect the prototype function

How can I get `this.getValue` when I call `$("#a").Test()`?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7p6nf2vr/2/)

Comment: Where do you want to get it?

Comment: $("#a").Test().getValue like this,not working

Comment: It will work without `this.each`, why are you looping it?

Comment: @ Spokey without this.each can call prototype function, such as $("#a").Test().init().I do not want to expose all function

Comment: I hope you're not doing this just to get the value. Don't use prototype if you don't want it to be public. You cannot return values from `.each()` http://jsfiddle.net/7p6nf2vr/7/

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on my iPad, so i can't test this code, but it looks like this is the problem.

Your `Test()` method returns a jQuery object, not a single value. You'll need to use `.get(0)` to get the actual value of the first item, and then you can use `.getValue` on that:

```
$("#a").Test().get(0).getValue
```